# What is a good internet site or book for a crash course in medical/epidemiology or social science statistics?

Tags: references, epidemiology, social-science

I am a PhD student in community nutrition.  My research (and the papers I read) run the gamut from pure social science to epidemiology.  Study designs range from observational data to quasi experimental and RCT’s.  I would like to brush up on learning what statistics are appropriate for different study designs and types of variables (continuous, categorical, ordinal, binary, quartiles/tertiles, etc.).
I am looking for a recommendation for a website or book that is easy-to-read and will give me a quick refresher on what statistics are appropriate in different scenarios.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the edX course [PH207x](https://www.edx.org/course/health-numbers-quantitative-methods-harvardx-ph207x) to be a great online content for starters. It may take some effort to go through the materials but I really think it's  excellent content-wise and by teaching.

From the course homepage

```
What you'll learn

    - How to analyze data sets using modern quantitative methods
    - How to discover patterns and extract knowledge from health data
    - The principles of biostatistics and epidemiology used for public health and clinical research, including: outcomes measurement, study design options -bias and confounding, probability and diagnostic tests, confidence intervals and hypothesis testing, power and sample size determinations, life tables and survival methods, regression methods (both, linear and logistic) and sample survey techniques
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice resource for general information on study designs, and statistical methods on the [Population Health Methods](https://www.mailman.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods) website from Columbia Mailman School of Public Health. The information there includes some basic definitions, applications and examples, and reading lists for additional information on a broad range of approaches that likely covers most of what you are looking for.